# Chrome under Docker: CAP_SYS_ADMIN vs privileged?

Tags: permissions, docker, chrome, namespaces

I am running chromedriver + chrome inside Docker in my test environment.

Everything was working fine until latest CoreOS upgrade.

These are the versions that seem to work:

```
VERSION=1185.5.0
VERSION_ID=1185.5.0
BUILD_ID=2016-12-07-0937
```

And this a newer version that causes chrome to coredump:

```
VERSION=1235.4.0
VERSION_ID=1235.4.0
BUILD_ID=2017-01-04-0450
```

Looking at changes, it seems docker was upgraded from 1.11.x to 1.12.x, which broke `setns()` call inside container. `setns()` is used by Chrome for creating a namespaces.

This are the example outputs:

```
jsosic-coreos-test-20161207 ~ # docker --version
Docker version 1.11.2, build bac3bae
```

From inside one container on this box:

```
[root@2939f21ecfaa /]# /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
[57:57:0107/015130:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] Gtk: cannot open display:
```

This is how the new version broke it:

```
jsosic-coreos-test-2017-01-04 ~ # docker --version
Docker version 1.12.3, build 34a2ead

[root@13ab34c36c82 /]# /opt/google/chrome/chrome
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported,
  Network namespace supported,
  but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What I have found out is that if I start the container with either `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` or `--privileged` - Chrome works as expected.

What is the difference between those two switches? What capabilities are enabled by `--privileged`?

And, can I allow `setns()` inside container without compromising security?

Comment: Thanks for this. I made an issue, using a lot of your stuff: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/496 I think it ought to get fixed

Comment: I am nearly 2 years too late, but there is a much better and safer solution in the ticket above if you are still interested.

Comment: If the original poster doesn't update the answer (he doesn't seem active on SO at all), let me know if you would be available to accept a different one. I wasted hours on this, I can only imagine how many hours we will save other people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAICS, the documentation [suggests](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) granting the capabilities needed for a container, rather than using the `--privileged` switch. Running in privileged mode [seems to grant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441605) [the container all capabilities](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/97660c6ec55f45416cb2b2d4c116267864b62b65/daemon/exec_linux.go) (exactly which those are is listed in the first URL, provided that the docs are up to date).

In short, I'd say that `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` grants a smaller subset of capabilities to the container, compared to the `--privileged` switch. Event the examples in the Docker documentation (first URL) seem to prefer just adding the `SYS_ADMIN` or `NET_ADMIN` capability where needed.

Comment: Thanks, `exec_linux.go` helped. I tried cloning docker repo to grep through it but since it took me couple of hours I just forgot about it :)

Comment: Just to run Chrome, there is a much better solution listed here: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/496#issuecomment-441149510 I think it would be very beneficial to update the answer so that people do what I explain in that very comment. Please let me know if you agree.

Answer (score 4):

One difference is that --privileged mounts /dev and /sys as RW, where as SYS_ADMIN mounts them as RO.
This means that a privileged container has full access to devices on the system. SYS_ADMIN doesn't give you that.

Comment: Great answer. A good example of that is vsphere-csi-plugin, which needs access to mounting/dismounting disks in a virtual machine and so it needs privileged access. sys_admin isn't enough.